# Navigation fails after updating WP7.0 project to WP7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Previosuly i have the **photo chooser task** in my app.

But **when i change to windows phone 7.1 the chooser is launched** but when i clicked on the image it suppose to navigate to another page.

The code:

```
photoChooserTask.Show();

void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)

{

   if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)

 {

   App.globalData.bitmapImage.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ChangePhoto.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

  }

  }
```

The error is once i clicked on the image "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();"

Comment: what is the exact exception that occurs that caused the debugger to break?  taht would be useful information.  is it only on the emulator? did you upgrade the project to 7.1, or is the phone running mango but the the project is still a 7.0 app?

Comment: Yes i upgraded the whole project. Did not show me exception. it just navigation fail

Comment: This should not have anything to do with the photoChooserTask. Could you verify this by putting a breakpoint at NavigationService.Navigate? If the breakpoint hits before the exception occurs the problems is related to navigating to the new page and you can forget about the photochoosertask in this context. Maybe something is wrong with ChangePhoto.xaml but we would need to see more code to verify

Answer (score 0):

There are `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` calls in the **app.xaml.cs** file.  They are there for unhandled exceptions and navigation errors.  The error will be in the method argument, review it when the debugger breaks.

Navigation errors are very likely incorrect URI paths.